# Adding custom .gitlab-ci.yml files?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I can see that [GitLab supports various templates](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/description_templates.html) for things such as licenses, issue templates and such, but I can't seem to find a way to add a template for `.gitlab-ci.yml files`. Can this be done on Gitlab CE?

Answer (score 0):

No, unless you can contribute (through merge request) to the [`gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-yml`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-yml) project, which is a collection of useful `.gitlab-ci.yml` templates.

Then, it is possible the API allows you to query that new template:
See [CE Get GitLab CI YML templates](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/templates/gitlab_ci_ymls.html#list-gitlab-ci-yml-templates)

For one template:

```
curl https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/templates/gitlab_ci_ymls/Ruby
```